# Number wrapper classes in Java

Tags: java

Im coming from PHP world and im so confused about how to think when you declare objects in java.

so when traditionally you do like this:

```
 Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
```

cause rect is a Rectangle datatype.

According to the java tutorial page a number wrapper class is a subclass to Number.
So its a class but when you instantiate it the tutorial did it like this:

```
 Integer x;
 x = 12;
```

Why isn´t it like this like the traditional way:

```
 Integer x = new Integer(12);
 or
 Integer x = new Integer();
```

And here is another example:

```
 String s = new Integer(i).toString();
```

So here s is a String object. that i get. But you got new Integer(i). Why new? What does it mean here and what happens when it sends 'i' to the constructor. Where can i see what the constructor is doing with the parameters in java API?

Many questions, but couldnt find sources on the net explaining it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firstly you can just use the primitive types:

```
int x = 12;
double d = 3.3456;
```

Secondly, you can optionally use the object wrappers for those numbers:

```
Integer x = new Integer(12);
Double d = new Double(3.3456);
```

Third, if you want the string representation you can do this simply with:

```
String s = Integer.toString(12);
```

or just:

```
int x;
String s = "x = " + x;
```

or even `printf()` like syntax:

```
int x = 12;
String s = String.format("x = %d", x);
```

Lastly, Java since version 5 has supported auto-boxing and unboxing, which may confuse you if you're not expecting it. For example:

```
Integer i = 1234; // autoboxes int to Integer
```

and

```
int i = new Integer(1234); // autounboxes Integer to an int
```

Just use the primitive types unless you need the `Number` wrappers. The most common reason to use them is to put them in collections (`List`s, etc).

Comment: thx for great explanation. is String s = Integer.toString(12); the same thing as String s = Integer(12).toString();

Answer (score 7):

What you're looking at in the first example is called autoboxing / autounboxing.  Java (starting with version 5) will automatically convert between `5` and `Integer.valueOf(5)`, which constructs a wrapper of type `Integer` from an int primitive.  But the latter (`Integer x = new Integer(12)`) is absolutely correct.

It doesnt work that way in the second case, however, if you wanted to write something like `5.toString()`.  Autoboxing only occurs when assigning a primitive to a wrapper type, or passing a primitive where the wrapper type is expected, etc.  Primitive types are not Objects and thus have no properties to be referenced.

Re: "why new", it's because all reference (non-primitive) types in Java are allocated dynamically, on the heap.  So (autoboxing aside), the only way to get an `Integer` (or other reference type) is to explicitly allocate space for one.

Comment: May be important to note that autoboxing is a feature of Java 5, so if you are using a previous version ( like 1.4 ) then you would be required to use the new Integer(5) syntax.

Comment: Technically, autoboxing converts from `5` to `Integer.valueOf(5)`. This makes it possible to share instances.

Comment: so Integer x = 12; is the autoboxing, that means x is declared as a object. and what is the code for the autounboxing?

Comment: Autoboxing means that the primitive value 12 is converted to an Integer object.  Autounboxing would look like this:  int x = new Integer(12)

Answer (score 2):

Some things the other answers have not adressed:

```
Integer x = new Integer();
```

This will not work because the `Integer` class does not have a no-args constructor (what would the resulting object's int value be?).

```
String s = new Integer(i).toString();
```

> So here s is a String object. that i
>   get. But you got new Integer(i). Why
>   new? What does it mean here and what
>   happens when it sends 'i' to the
>   constructor. Where can i see what the
>   constructor is doing with the
>   parameters in java API?

It means the same as above: an `Integer` object is created, passed the content of the variable `i` (probably a loop index) as constructor argument, and then the resulting object's `toString()` method is called, which yields a string representation of the number.

As for where you can look up such things, the [Java API doc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/) describes all aspects of the standard API in detail. If that is not enough, Sun's JDK comes with the complete source code of the standard API. When you install the JDK you have the option to get this source code, and most IDEs will allow you to jump to it easily.

Comment: Yeah, try Ctrl+Shift+Space (assuming everythign is set up ok)

Comment: Indeed it does. If you press Ctrl-Space while typing an identifier (such as a class or method name) it will show a list of all possible completions including the API doc. And if you keep Ctrl pressed and click on an identifier, it will jump to the source code where it's defined. These functionality is also available via the context menu.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to objects, Java also includes primitive datatypes such as boolean, byte, int, long, char, float, double.  All of these are referred to in lower case and are used with literal values.  These are always passed by value.

There are also matching Number objects Boolean, Byte, Integer, Long, etc that can be used which, like all objects, are passed by reference instead.  Because these are objects rather than primitives there are different performance implications and characteristics to watch out for.

Modern Java has auto boxing and auto unboxing to silently convert between the primitives and Objects which allow the syntax as you've used it `Integer i = 5` to autobox a primitive `5` into an Object `Integer`.  Previously you would have had to either use the primitive `int i = 5` or explicit object based syntax `Integer i = new Integer(5)` rather than mixing types as you can now.

Answer (score 1):

This strange behavior:

```
Integer x;
x = 12;
```

Is due to java [autoboxing](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html).

Some history:

Prior to Java 1.5 it was not allowed. You had primitives ( `int, char, byte, boolean, float, double,long` ) and the rest in the Java world were classes ( including the corresponging wrappers: `Integer, Character, Byte, Booelan, Float, Double, Long` ) .

The core data structures of Java worked with Objects, so if you needed to store numbers into a list you had to "wrap" your value ( the wrappers are just regular classes that hold a primitive type )

For instance this may be my own `int` wrapper:

```
 public class Entero { // integer in spanish... :P 
     private final int wrappedInt;

     public Entero( int i ) {
         this.wrappedInt = i;
     }

     public int getEntero() {
         return wrappedInt;
     }
 }
```

Nothing fancy, that's in general terms how the "wrapper" classes are implemented ( of course there are a lot of utility methods there )

So, again, if you wanted to use it in a List ( which only holds Objects )  you'll have to:

```
 List list = // get the list from somewhere.... 
 list.add( new Integer( 1024 ) ); // wrap it
 .... 
 // use the list and at some point iterate it:
 Iterator iterator = list.iterator();
 while( iterator.hasNext() ) {
     Integer e = ( Integer ) iterator.next(); // unwrap it
     i = e.intValue();
 }
```

Calling

```
 list.add( 1024 )
```

Directly wasn't possible, because `1024` is an `int` literal, not an object.

Tons of code were written like this, by years.

Since Java 1.5  added autoboxing that basically is syntactic sugar, now "new Integer( i )/ integer.intValue()" are injected under the hood by the compiler  and the code became:

```
list.add( 1024 ); // wrapped in the compiled code in the the .class file that is.
....
Iterator i = list.iterator();
while( i.hasNext() ) {
    int i = ( Integer ) i.next(); // unwrapped for you by the compiler under the hood
}
```

Removing the wrapping process from the source code.

Additionally, with generics, you saved the casting also:

```
 List<Integer> list = .... // <- you still have to say the list is of "Integers" not "int"

 .... 
 Iterator<Integer> i = list.iterator(); // The iterator has to use the "<Integer>"  generic mark
 while( i.hasNext() ){
     int x = i.next(); // but you can get the value directly. 
 }
```

Basically generics is a mark to say "check what gets used is of this type and don't bother me with casting anymore", but  generics are another topic.